# Ember component not updating in integration test when injected service is updated

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I have a side-bar component which relies on side-bar service which is injected into it via initializer.

the component then has a computed property title which is tied to the same property on the service:

```
title: function () {
  return this.get('sideBarService.title');
}.property('sideBarService.title'),
```

This works in the app itself but I cannot get the component to update in an integration test when the service is upated.

Here is my non working integration test:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';

var application, container, sideBarService;

moduleForComponent('side-bar', 'Integration | side-bar',{
  integration: true,
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
    container = application.__container__;
    sideBarService = container.lookup('service:side-bar');
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('it displays the correct title', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  Ember.run(function () {
    sideBarService.set('title', 'Hello');
  });

  this.render(hbs`
    {{side-bar}}
  `);

  var content = this.$('.side-bar-content .title').text().trim();
  var serviceTitle = sideBarService.get('title');
  // fails     
  assert.deepEqual(content, serviceTitle);
});
```

Interestingly, if I debug in the test and grab the component with the console and then grab the sideBarService off of the component, it is aware of the updated title value and even the value title on the component itself seems to be updated but the dom never gets updated:

```
//debugged in browser console
var sb = container.lookup('component:side-bar')
undefined

sb.get('title')
"Hello"

sb.get('sideBarService.title')
"Hello"

this.$('.title').text().trim()
""
```

Is this a run loop issue? If so what do I need to do to set it off?

edit: In regards to Toran's comment. Does this look right?

```
  var done = assert.async();
  var content = this.$('.side-bar-content .title').text().trim();
  var serviceTitle = sideBarService.get('title');
  setTimeout(function() {
    assert.deepEqual(content, serviceTitle);
    done();
  });
```

Comment: often w/ async code I've found that integration tests require the "var done = assert.async()" plus a setTimeout of 1 (then when I do the assertion and fire the done() I can verify the event loop has done it's job as expected). Try that and let me know if it works/or if you need some hands on help

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the response but no look. I'm adding a snippet above to show what I did just in case I did not call assert async  correctly

Comment: @ToranBillups I would definitely take you up on the offer to dig into this more! Is there a best way to follow up with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go about fixing this by avoiding the injection in the initializer and instead using the `Ember.inject.service` helper.

```
// component

import Ember from 'ember'

const { Component, inject, computed } = Ember;
const { service } = inject;
const { alias } = computed;

export default Component.extend({

  sideBarService: service('side-bar'),

  title: alias('sideBarService.title')

});
```

Then in your test, you can pass the service when you use the component.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';

var application, container, sideBarService;

moduleForComponent('side-bar', 'Integration | side-bar',{
  integration: true,
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('it displays the correct title', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  this.set('sideBarService', Ember.Object.create({
    title: 'hello'
  }));

  this.render(hbs`
    {{side-bar sideBarService=sideBarService}}
  `);

  var title = this.$('.side-bar-content .title').text().trim();
  assert.equal(title, 'hello'); // Hopefully passes
});
```